# Do something on a per-instances basis of custom NSView drop event

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

So I have two instances of a custom NSView in my app delegate

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet SYDropView *sourceView;
@property (assign) IBOutlet SYDropView *destView;
```

SYDropView has a `currPath` ivar that gets updated when a folder is dropped on it, which works fine.

Now, if I wanted to do something extra, like update a label, depending on which SYDropView was changed, how do I differentiate between the instances to check if the sourceView or destView was changed? I need to know which one was changed so I can update the proper label. Do I pass the sender to the app delegate on drop and do something with that?

Comment: Can you paste your more code here. So that it will be easy to identify your issue??

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to write a protocol that defines a delegate for your `SYDropView`, with a method like this one:

```
@protocol SYDropViewDelegate

- (void) folderDroppedOnView: (SYDropView*) view;

@end
```

You should call this method from the `SYDropView` when the folder gets dropped, so that you can recognize which view did notice the event.

To easily set the delegate of the views you can just override the setters:

```
- (void) setSourceView: (SYDropView*) sourceView {
    _sourceView= sourceView;
    _sourceView.delegate= self;
}
```

And the same for `setDestView`.